# Realm : getTable() delete all then copyToRealm

Tags: realm

I have this piece of code and its goal is to delete all the recipe objects and after the deletion of such objects, i will populate the table again with new recipes from the list.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.getTable(Recipe.class).clear();
realm.copyToRealm(list);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

The problem of this code is that it throws this exception

```
Value already exists: 18
io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: 18
    at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:636)
    at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRowWithPrimaryKey(Table.java:408)
    at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:678)
    at io.realm.IngredientTypeRealmProxy.copy(IngredientTypeRealmProxy.java:300)
    at io.realm.IngredientTypeRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(IngredientTypeRealmProxy.java:295)     at io.realm.IngredientRealmProxy.copy(IngredientRealmProxy.java:470)
    at io.realm.IngredientRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(IngredientRealmProxy.java:451)
    at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:208)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1166)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealm(Realm.java:697)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealm(Realm.java:735)
    at team.jcandfriends.namnam.ui.HardRefreshActivity$1.onNext(HardRefreshActivity.java:152)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:202)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:162)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

My question is why is this happening when in the first place, i deleted all the objects first using `realm.getTable(Recipe.class).clear()`, so I assumed that it is already safe to use `realm.copyToRealm(list)` since the table is already empty. I'm sorry for my ignorance, I love realm, like really :)

I get my data from here: https://namnamnam.herokuapp.com/api/recipes

Comment: `getTable` is an internal API, and it will be removed from public API very soon. You can just use `Realm.clear` instead. For the `RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException` issue, i believe there is a duplicated pk in the list you passed. Can you please check it? Or share the content of the list.

Comment: i updated my post to include the data source. For the ```Realm.clear``` thing, i used ```Realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll().clear()``` and ```Realm.allObjects(Recipe.class).clear()```

Comment: It is a long list :) I think the problem is there will be same sub-objects, and when you call `copyToRealm` will do strict checking even for the sub-objects to make sure nothing can be duplicated. I think in your case, it is totally safe to just use `copyToRealmOrUpdate`. Note that if there are different object with same pk, the earlier one will be overwritten.

Comment: you are actually right sir, now I know what the culprit is, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.where(Recipe.class).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
        realm.insertOrUpdate(list);
    }
});
```

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention that i've already tried this. and this ```realm.allObjects(Recipe.class).clear()```

Comment: That **is** strange. I expected that to work. Maybe it would work with `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` then instead?

Comment: it is strange indeed, using ```copyToRealmOrUpdate()``` works though

Comment: I think that's a bug, but maybe what happens is that the previous object is invalidated, but not completely removed until you commit the transaction; something like that. I'm not a spokesperson for Realm, so I can't actually be sure! I just know that I used to do this all the time and using `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` worked as intended.